# Is libfuse2 safe to install on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS?

Tags: 22.04, lts, fuse

According to my research 'fuse' will break Ubuntu. I actually just had to do a complete re-install (not sure if that is what it was.) All to say - I have an appimage that I need to install (DaVinci Resolve Studio) Will 'libfuse2' break my system?

Thank you in advance:D

Comment: I don't see the point to your question, it's in repositories (`libfuse2 | 2.9.9-5ubuntu3         | jammy/universe   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`) and thus received CI & some QA testing & passed.  I also did my last (*non-destructive*) *jammy* re-install on the weekend as a QA-test without issue; my additional (*manually installed*) apps were auto-reinstalled, my data files untouched as expected.. and my packages updated thru re-install. What problem have you encountered?

Comment: @guiverc Honestly not sure what happened. I'm not the best with the whole back end of Ubuntu/Linux. I'm glad you have it working nice and smoothly though!! I just wanted to make sure libfuse2 was not going to reset me XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installed from the Ubuntu repositories onto a properly functioning system, libfuse2 certainly WON'T break Ubuntu.

If you encounter FUSE-related problems that you can reproduce in a test environment, then please file a bug report.

Note that a system that is "kind-of" working or has ongoing unresolved errors in the logs does not not meet the "properly functioning" criteria.

Comment: Thank you so much!!